# How to call all the functions in Selenium when a page is refreshed?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I was using selenium automation in Python on a login page. I have send my keys in email and password textbox using:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("loginId").sendKeys("mailid")
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_Keys("password")
```

When I click on **Log In** button then the page is refreshed and just in case if my id and password combination is wrong. But how can I automate so that when my page is refreshed, at least the id and pass field is filled again? Or that means if my password is wrong and I've redirected to the same page again, how can I fill those boxes again. How to check if the page is refreshed automatically or not?

```
def login():
     driver.find_element_by_id("usernameId").send_keys('username')
     driver.find_element_by_id("pwd").send_keys('password')
     driver.find_element_by_id("logIn").click()
     # tell me what to write here in case I got an error saying invalid id and pass combination.

login()
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you are testing for the error message, then you can check that. If not, then probably you should provide valid credentials. In (automated) testing it makes little sense to try and redo stuff, you normally strive to make testcases short and concise.If you want to test for the redo, then just write the same code again. (With a different pass ??)

Comment: There's a captcha box, let's say I entered an incorrect captcha.

Comment: Why would you do that in a testcase? Well anyway, have you tried just writing the same lines again ? What have you tried, and what is it that does not work?

Comment: There's a captcha box, let's say I entered an incorrect captcha. 
And let's say the page refreshed with a pop saying "incorrect captcha".
In that case,I want id and pass text fields to be entered automatically.What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Because many times I need a lot of things that are better done manually, logins, capcha, robot checks, authentications, extensions certain cookies, etc

I use folders as profiles, I run:

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=custom_folder_1") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

Then I manually install the Extensions and do the logins I need now every-time I start the Webdriver with that folder everything is there

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=custom_folder_1") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("www.google.com") #Now you can see the logins done are present
```

The advantage is you can use multiple folders with different setting and Extensions without the need to install and uninstall Extensions, change settings, change logins etc